CORRUPTED_ENTITY video post linkedin api
We try to make video posts with the linkedin API, in the whole process of upload initialization, video segmentation, upload, upload finalization and post I have no errors, we even managed to publish the first time but now no more posts are published.
In the same way, when I try to publish a duplicate linkedin post, it refuses because it's a duplicate post.

CODE:
Upload of the video:
    async initializeUploadToLinkedinVideo(filePath) {
        const params = [
            { value: this.profileUrn, name: 'profileUrn' },
            { value: this.token, name: 'token' },
            { value: filePath, name: 'filePath' }
        ]
        const error = verifyParams(params)
        if (error) {
            return error
        }

        let fileSize
        try {
            fileSize = await getSize(filePath)
            if (fileSize === 0) {
                return { error: 'File size is 0' }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error getting file size:', e)
            return { error: 'Failed to get file size' }
        }

        try {
            const uploadResponse = await axios.post(
                `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos?action=initializeUpload`,
                {
                    initializeUploadRequest: {
                        owner: this.profileUrn,
                        fileSizeBytes: fileSize,
                        uploadCaptions: false,
                        uploadThumbnail: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`,
                        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
                        'LinkedIn-Version': '202405',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            )
            return uploadResponse.data
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Error during LinkedIn initialize upload video:`, e.response ? e.response.data : e.message)
            return { error: 'Failed to upload to LinkedIn' }
        }
    }

    async uploadToLinkedinVideo(filePath, uploadInstructions) {
        const params = [
            { value: this.token, name: 'token'},
            { value: uploadInstructions, name: 'uploadInstructions' },
            { value: filePath, name: 'filePath' }
        ]
        const error = verifyParams(params)
        if (error) {
            return error
        }

        let videoSplit
        try {
            videoSplit = await videoSplitter(filePath, uploadInstructions)
            if (videoSplit?.error) {
                console.error('Error splitting video:', videoSplit.error)
                return videoSplit
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error splitting video:', e)
            return { error: 'Failed to split video' }
        }

        console.log('videoSplit:', videoSplit)

        try {
            const uploadPromises = videoSplit.map(async (video) => {
                const { outputFilePath, uploadUrl } = video
                const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(outputFilePath)
                const formData = new FormData()
                formData.append('file', fileStream)

                const uploadResponse = await axios.put(uploadUrl, formData,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            ...formData.getHeaders()
                        }
                    }
                )
                return {
                    status: uploadResponse.status,
                    etag: uploadResponse.headers.etag
                }
            })
            return await Promise.all(uploadPromises)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error during LinkedIn upload video:', e.response ? e.response.data : e.message)
            return { error: 'Failed to upload to LinkedIn' }
        }
    }

    async finalizeVideoUpload(videoUrn, eTags) {
        const params = [
            { value: this.token, name: 'token' },
            { value: videoUrn, name: 'videoUrn' }
        ]
        const error = verifyParams(params)
        if (error) {
            return error
        }

        try {
            const finalizeResponse = await axios.post(
                `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos?action=finalizeUpload`,
                {
                    finalizeUploadRequest: {
                        video: videoUrn,
                        uploadToken: "",
                        uploadedPartIds: eTags
                    }
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.token}`,
                        "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
                        "LinkedIn-Version": "202405",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            )
            return finalizeResponse.status
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error during LinkedIn finalize video upload:', e.response ? e.response.data : e.message)
            return { error: 'Failed to finalize video upload' }
        }
    }

    async initializeAndUploadToLinkedinVideo(filePath) {
        const initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse = await this.initializeUploadToLinkedinVideo(filePath)
        console.log('initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse:', initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse)
        if (initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse?.error) {
            return initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse
        }

        const videoUrn = initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse?.value?.video
        if (!videoUrn) {
            return { error: 'Failed to get video URN' }
        }

        const uploadInstructions = initializeUploadToLinkedinResponse?.value?.uploadInstructions
        console.log('uploadInstructions:', uploadInstructions)
        if (!uploadInstructions) {
            return { error: 'Failed to get upload instructions' }
        }

        const uploadToLinkedinResponse = await this.uploadToLinkedinVideo(filePath, uploadInstructions)
        console.log('uploadToLinkedinResponse:', uploadToLinkedinResponse)
        if (uploadToLinkedinResponse?.error) {
            return uploadToLinkedinResponse
        }

        const eTags = uploadToLinkedinResponse.map(upload => upload.etag)
        const finalizeVideoUploadResponse = await this.finalizeVideoUpload(videoUrn, eTags)
        console.log('finalizeVideoUploadResponse:', finalizeVideoUploadResponse)
        if (finalizeVideoUploadResponse?.error) {
            return finalizeVideoUploadResponse
        }
        if (finalizeVideoUploadResponse !== 200) {
            return { error: 'Failed to finalize video upload' }
        }

        return videoUrn
    }

NOTE: verifyParams(), getSize() and videoSplitter() are defined in an other file, below the function used to split the video according to the documentation
exports.videoSplitter = async (filePath, uploadInstructions) => {
    const outputDir = `./uploads/linkedin/${filePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]}`

    if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(outputDir, { recursive: true })
    }

    const videoPaths = []

    const splitPromise = uploadInstructions.map((range, index) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const { firstByte, lastByte, uploadUrl } = range
            const outputFilePath = `${outputDir}/segment_${index + 1}.mp4`
            // Adjust the end position to include the last byte
            const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { start: firstByte, end: lastByte })
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath)

            readStream.pipe(writeStream)

            readStream.on('end', () => {
                console.log(`Segment ${index + 1} written successfully`)
                const absolutePath = fs.realpathSync(outputFilePath)
                videoPaths.push({ outputFilePath: absolutePath, uploadUrl })
                resolve()
            })

            readStream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.error(`Error reading segment ${index + 1}:`, err)
                reject(err)
            })

            writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.error(`Error writing segment ${index + 1}:`, err)
                reject(err)
            })
        })
    })

    try {
        await Promise.all(splitPromise)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error splitting video:', e)
        return { error: 'Failed to split video', details: e }
    }

    if (videoPaths.length !== uploadInstructions.length) {
        return { error: 'Failed to split video' }
    }

    return videoPaths
}

Below the request to post and get a video:
Post:
POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
Linkedin-Version: 202405
X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:<ORGANIZATION_ID>",
  "commentary": "Post video from api test longer /3!",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
    "targetEntities": [],
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "content": {
    "media": {
      "title": "Post video from api test longer /2!",
      "id": "urn:li:video:<VIDEO_ID>"
    }
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}

get:
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos/urn:li:video:<VIDEO_ID>
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
Linkedin-Version: 202405
Content-Type: application/json

# Response:

{
  "owner": "urn:li:organization:<ORGANIZATION_ID>",
  "processingFailureReason": "CORRUPTED_ENTITY",
  "id": "urn:li:video:<VIDEO_ID>",
  "status": "PROCESSING_FAILED"
}

I also tried this but I have an issue when splitting the video.
I have the same issue when trying to upload video < 4Mb (unsplitted video)

I'd talk to LinkedIn directly about this to get more details about the corrupted_entity, e.g. raise a Zendesk ticket.

When you say duplicates are getting rejected as duplicates, that sounds correct though doesn't it? Unless you're saying failed videos are being counted for duplicates too.

The problem was in the way the videos were split in videoSplitter(), here is a corrected function
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exports.videoSplitter = async (filePath, uploadInstructions) => {
    const outputDir = path.join('./uploads/linkedin', path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath)))

    if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(outputDir, { recursive: true })
    }

    const videoPaths = []

    const splitCommand = `split -b 4194303 ${filePath} ${path.join(outputDir, 'part-')}`

    try {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec(splitCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`Error splitting video: ${error}`)
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve()
                }
            })
        })

        const partFiles = fs.readdirSync(outputDir).filter(file => file.startsWith('part-'))

        if (partFiles.length !== uploadInstructions.length) {
            return { error: 'Failed to split video: mismatch between number of parts and upload instructions' }
        }

        partFiles.forEach((file, index) => {
            const absolutePath = fs.realpathSync(path.join(outputDir, file))
            const uploadUrl = uploadInstructions[index].uploadUrl
            videoPaths.push({ outputFilePath: absolutePath, uploadUrl })
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error splitting video:', e)
        return { error: 'Failed to split video', details: e }
    }

    return videoPaths
}


